# How to set stack size in TThread?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I set a custom stack size in `TThread`? I am trying to reintroduce the constructor of `TThread` but it says that `ThreadProc` is missing yet its right there in `System.Classes`.

```
type
  TThreadHelper = class helper for TThread
    constructor Create(const CreateSuspended: Boolean = False; const StackSize: Integer = 0); reintroduce;
 end;

{ TThreadHelper }

constructor TThreadHelper.Create(const CreateSuspended: Boolean; const StackSize: Integer);
begin
  Self.FSuspended := not Self.FExternalThread;
  Self.FCreateSuspended := CreateSuspended and not Self.FExternalThread;
  if not Self.FExternalThread then
  begin
    Self.FHandle := BeginThread(nil, StackSize, @ThreadProc, Pointer(Self), CREATE_SUSPENDED, Self.FThreadID);
    if Self.FHandle = 0 then
    raise EThread.CreateResFmt(@SThreadCreateError, [SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]);
  end
  else
  begin
    Self.FHandle := Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentThread;
    Self.FThreadId := GetCurrentThreadId;
  end;
end;
```

> [dcc32 Error] Project5.dpr(29): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'ThreadProc'

Comment: The `ThreadProc` function is not for public use. It would have been defined in the `interface` part of the unit as well. Hence the compiler cannot see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know, if you can set stack size after a thread is created. Maybe [`SetThreadStackGuarantee`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be helpful?

You can create a thread from scratch by using `BeginThread`, but it is quite complicated. I have here a workaround by using `Detours`. Note that there are several `Detours` variants. I think only the `Cromis.Detours` is x64 compatible.

```
unit IndividualStackSizeForThread;

interface

uses 
  System.Classes,
  Cromis.Detours { http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/ };

type
  TThreadHelper = class helper for TThread
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; StackSize: LongWord);
 end;

implementation

var
  TrampolineBeginThread: function(SecurityAttributes: Pointer; StackSize: LongWord;
    ThreadFunc: TThreadFunc; Parameter: Pointer; CreationFlags: LongWord; 
    var ThreadId: TThreadID): THandle = nil;

threadvar
  StackSizeOverride: LongWord;

function InterceptBeginThread(SecurityAttributes: Pointer; StackSize: LongWord;
  ThreadFunc: TThreadFunc; Parameter: Pointer; CreationFlags: LongWord;
  var ThreadId: TThreadID): THandle;
const
  STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION = $00010000; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx
begin
  if StackSizeOverride <> 0 then
  begin
    CreationFlags := CreationFlags or STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION;
    StackSize := StackSizeOverride;
    StackSizeOverride := 0;
  end;

  Result := TrampolineBeginThread(SecurityAttributes, StackSize, ThreadFunc, 
    Parameter, CreationFlags, ThreadId);
end;

constructor TThreadHelper.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; StackSize: LongWord);
begin
  StackSizeOverride := StackSize;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

initialization

TrampolineBeginThread := InterceptCreate(@BeginThread, @InterceptBeginThread);

finalization

InterceptRemove(@TrampolineBeginThread, @InterceptBeginThread);

end.
```

I do not know why Embt does not allow programmer to specify the stack size, if someone knows the reason, it will be very interesting to me.

Answer (score 3):

There is simply no way to control the stack size using `TThread`. For whatever reason, the designers of `TThread` failed to include a stack size parameter in the constructor of `TThread`. This is clearly an omission. You should call `BeginThread` or `CreateThread` directly.

If you are simply desperate to make your hack work then you'll need to find the address of the  `ThreadProc` function declared in the implementation section of the `Classes` unit. Some possible approaches:

1. Disassemble `TThread.Create` at runtime to read out the address of `ThreadProc`.
2. Create a dummy thread that looks at its call stack to find the address of `ThreadProc`.
3. Hook `BeginThread` using a detour. Create a dummy thread. Note the address of the thread procedure passed. That is `ThreadProc`.

A good source of ideas for this sort of hacking is the source code for `madExcept`.

Another way to apply the hack would again be to use a detour on `BeginThread`. You could then use a thread local variable to supply the stack size. A value of `high(LongWord)` for that thread local variable would mean "use the value passed as a parameter", and any other value would be the value used by the detoured `BeginThread`.

Comment: You can use whatever detour library you like

Answer (score 3):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140564/224704) points out, you can't control the stack size for threads created with `TThread` class. You would have to create the actual thread yourself using either `BeginThread` or `CreateThread`.

However, if you don't need different stack sizes for each thread in your application:
Then you can set the default stack size using linking options for *Min stack size* and *Max stack size*.

Either set the option in project options, or use the directives: `{$M minstacksize,maxstacksize} {$MINSTACKSIZE number} {$MAXSTACKSIZE number}`

Answer (score 3):

For Delphi 10.3 RIO and later, there is now an overloaded constructor that allows you to set the ReservedStackSize for TThread on the Windows platform.

```
{$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ReservedStackSize: NativeUInt); overload;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
```